# In PHP is there an elegant way to process JSON with deeply nested, optional nodes?

Tags: php, json

I'm using the Oxford Dictionary API to look up word definitions. The JSON returned could be 13 levels deep or more. It's arrays of objects, and I can never be certain an object will exist at any point.

I want to return a simple array of the definitions, stored in `$list`.

So I found myself writing this horror story:

```
$list = [];
$data = json_decode( $response->getBody() );

//oh gross
if( isset( $data->results ) ) {
    foreach( $data->results as $r ) {
        if( isset( $r->lexicalEntries ) ) {
            foreach( $r->lexicalEntries as $l ) {
                if( isset( $l->entries ) ) {
                    foreach( $l->entries as $e ) {
                        if( isset( $e->senses ) ) {
                            foreach( $e->senses as $s ) {
                                if( isset( $s->definitions ) ) {
                                    foreach( $s->definitions as $d ) {
                                        $list[] = [
                                            'word' => $r->word,
                                            'definition' => $d
                                        ];
                                    }
                                }

                                if( isset( $s->subsenses ) ) {
                                    foreach( $s->subsenses as $ss ) {
                                        if( isset( $ss->definitions ) ) {
                                            foreach( $ss->definitions as $d ) {
                                                $list[] = [
                                                    'word' => $r->word,
                                                    'definition' => $d
                                                ];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return $list;
```

Which works, but is just completely nasty.

I've considered a recursive function but not sure that would be any more readable.

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: can you show a response using `json_decode($response->getBody(), true);` to make it an associative array

Comment: Could you include a basic API response in pastebin or something?

Comment: neil - Sample response is here: http://pastebin.com/ANVPwpCq ... synthet1c - thanks, tried that but still came across the undefined index issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I gotta be honest as that result of your method is just an array with two indexes, where `word` is always the same and the `definition` is different. If you really want `$r->word` stored with that `definition` than there is little that can be done.

However, you can shorten your `isset()` code with:

1. *tanery operator* with PHP version < 7
2. *null coalesce operator* with PHP >= 7.

And example for both versions:

```
// PHP < 7.
foreach(isset($data['results']) ? $data['results'] : [] as $value){}

// PHP > 7
foreach($data['results'] ?? [] as $value){}
```

However, this is all just to suppress the error reporting, you can temporarily turn it off and back on again and just assume the index exist and forget about the `isset()`.

---

I've defined the data like so:

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

As I prefer arrays over objects in this occasion, and a copy of your method of doing things with the PHP 7 null coalesce operator:

```
foreach($data['results'] ?? [] as $r){
  foreach($r['lexicalEntries'] ?? [] as $l){
    foreach($l['entries'] ?? [] as $e){
      foreach($e['senses'] ?? [] as $s){
        foreach( $s['definitions'] ?? [] as $d){
          $list[] = [
            'word' => $r['word'],
            'definition' => $d
          ];
        }

        foreach($s['subsenses'] ?? [] as $ss){
          foreach( $ss['definitions'] ?? [] as $d){
            $list[] = [
              'word' => $r['word'],
              'definition' => $d
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

print_r($list);
```

However, there are other ways you can do this and that is to flatten the array. There are multiple ways you can do this, I prefer a generator however recursive generators are introduced in PHP 7 and above.

```
// This is a generator function, it flattens the entire given array.
// It yields an array containing the key and value on each iteration.
function array_walk_generator($array){
  foreach($array as $k => $v){
    yield $k => $v;

    if(is_array($v)){
      yield from array_walk_generator($v);
    }
  }
}

foreach($data['results'] as $result){
  $list = [];

  foreach(array_walk_generator($result) as $k => $v){
    if($k == 'definitions' && is_array($v)){
      $list[] = $v[0];
    }
  }

  $return[] = [
    'word' => $result['word'],
    'definitions' => array_values(array_filter($list))
  ];
}

print_r($return);
```

This way you have in my opinion a better organized array, and this way it doesn't really care how the definitions are formatted.

Comment: Thanks for that! Didn't know about the null coalescing operator. And the recursive generator code looks good. I mainly wanted to check there wasn't something obvious I was missing.